# can not pushViewController at all

Tags: iphone, pushviewcontroller

I am adding a button into UITableView by doing the following

```
 // Add checkOut button
    UIView      *viewHolder =   [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 165)];
    UIButton    *checkOut   =   [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    CGRect      buttonRect  =   CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width - 220.)/2, 30, 220., 44.);

    [checkOut setTitle:@"Check out" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [checkOut addTarget:self action:@selector(goToCheckOut) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [checkOut setFrame:buttonRect];
    [viewHolder addSubview:checkOut];
    self.shoppingListTable.tableFooterView  =   viewHolder;
```

and goToCheckOut does :

```
#pragma mark - goToCheckOut
- (void)goToCheckOut {
    NSLog(@"goToCheckOut");
    AnotherViewController  *controller =   [[AnotherViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AnotherViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

When I click on the button, the log is showing

```
goToCheckOut
```

but I am not being navigated to another view controller.

Does any body know why ? Please help. Thanks

---

@pgb : you are rite about that some how. the uiviewcontroller in tab bar is my own view controller...However, I dont have uitabbarviewcontroller.Instead, I have `uiviewcontroller` with `uitabar` in it.To display the view when clicking on each uitab bar button, I am doing like the following

```
#pragma mark - TabBarDelegate
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item {
    // firstViewController section
    if ( item.tag == 0 ) {
        [self.firstViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
        [self.secondViewControoler.view   removeFromSuperview];
        self.title   =   @"First View Controller";
        [self.view insertSubview:self.firstViewController.view belowSubview:taBar];
    }
    // secondViewController section
    else if (item.tag == 1){
        [self.firstViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
        [self.secondViewControoler.view   removeFromSuperview];
        self.title    =   @"Second View Controller";
        frame.origin.x      =   [self horizontalCoordinateAt:item.tag + 2];
        [self.view insertSubview:self.secondViewControoler.view belowSubview:taBar];
    }

}
```

The current structure I am having now is

```
UIViewController0 ( it is also a navigationController)
  UIViewController1
  UIViewController2
    UITabBar
      FirstViewController
      SecondViewController
```

How it is possible to change so that I can do pushViewController in First and SecondViewController.

Comment: Is your current view controller contained within a navigation controller?  i.e. Is `self.navigationController` not `nil`?

Comment: i just double check and it is not. the story is I have a big view A with 4 uitabBars and this view ( the one containing uitableview + checkout button )is the current view when I click on the third uitabBar

Comment: Your view is not in a navigation controller?  or `self.navigationController` is not nil?

Comment: Are you sure that you use the correct name of the nib ?

Comment: the big view A is in navigation controller.It has an array of 4 view controllers.When I click on the uitabBar, I just add a view of particular view controller from an array to the view of itself...I do this because I want to keep uitab bar at the bottoms for every views....

Comment: @iArezki : I am positive about that....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, I would guess that the `UIViewController` you are setting in the tab view controller is your own view controller and not a `UINavigationController`.

You hierarchy needs to be:

```
UITabViewController
   UINavigationController
     YourCustomViewController
   UINavigationController
     OtherCustomViewController
```

Instead, my guess is that you have the following hierarchy:

```
UITabViewController
   YourCustomViewController
   OtherCustomViewController
```

`self.navigationController` might not be `nil`, since you may be creating a `UINavigationController`, but you are -again, my guess- failing to set the navigationController as the view controller handled by the tab view controller.

Answer (score 0):

I found my own solution for this issue. What I did is :

```
1. Create a delegate with a callback method in each FirstViewController and SecondViewController
2. Make UIViewController2 conform delegate of first and second view controller
3. Implement the method in delegate ( a call back ) such as pushViewController....
```